# Every state corresponds to a density operator

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces

$\DeclareMathOperator{\tr}{tr}$Let $H$ be a separable complex Hilbert space and $L(H)$ be all bounded linear operators on $H$.

- Define a **state** to be a bounded linear functional  $\phi: L(H)\rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ such that $\phi(I)=1$ and $\phi (A) \ge 0$ for all $A \ge 0$.
- Define a **density operator** $\rho$ to be a bounded positive ($\ge 0$) linear operator on $H$ such that $\tr(\rho)=1$.

Then how would you prove that the mapping $\rho \mapsto \tr(\cdot \rho)$ is a bijective map from density operators to states on $H$? I can prove everything else except for surjectivity.

Comment: $L(H)$ shoud be a Hilbert space with the $tr(AB^*)$ as scalar product. The states are bounded linear functionals, which means they admit a Riesz representation. Due to the properties of the states the representing "vector", i.e. operator in this case, admits the given properties.

Comment: Are you thinking of Hilbert-Schmidt operators? Because unless $H$ is finite-dimensional, $L(H)$ should be bigger than the space of Hilbert-Schmidt operators.

Comment: You should be able to generalize it to the whole L(H) using some convergence argument

Comment: @Mick I’m not totally sure if that’s possible, since Hilbert Schmidt operators are compact and compact operators are closed in norm topology in $L(H)$, I don’t think it’s possible to approximate all $L(H)$ with Hilbert Schmidt operators

Comment: Have you tried proving by contradiction?

Comment: https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=https://projecteuclid.org/download/pdf_1/euclid.pjm/1102635970&ved=2ahUKEwiPzcy6woXoAhUrQEEAHd7zAZMQFjAEegQIBhAB&usg=AOvVaw1rE-KbJnZ-I7lbDRfriinP maybe this can help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $H$ is infinite-dimensional, there are states on $L(H)$ that are not induced by density operators. Let $K(H)$ denote the set of compact operators on $H$ and consider the functional $\tilde \phi\colon K(H)+\mathbb{C}\mathrm{id}\to \mathbb{C},\,T+\lambda\mathrm{id}\mapsto \lambda$.

By Hahn-Banach, it has an extension $\phi$ to $L(H)$ with equal norm (i.e. norm $1$). Since additionally $\phi(\mathrm{id})=1$, this means that $\phi$ is a state. But if $\phi$ were of the form $\phi=\mathrm{tr}(\,\cdot\,\rho)$ for some density matrix $\rho$, we would have $0=\phi(T)=\mathrm{tr}(T\rho)$ for every compact $T$, hence $\rho=0$, a contradiction.

States of the form $\mathrm{tr}(\,\cdot\,\rho)$ for some density matrix $\rho$ are exactly the *normal* states, i.e. states that are continuous with respect to the $\sigma$-weak operator topology (there is a long list of equivalent definitions).

One standard reference for these questions is Blackadar's book on operator algebras, in this case Theorem III.2.1.4.

Comment: You need the extension to be positive, but I believe there is a version of Hahn-Banach that allows this.

Comment: @s.harp Every functional that satisfies $\phi(1)=\|\phi\|=1$ is automatically positive (and I think any "positive" version of Hahn-Banach is based on this fact).

Comment: Oh yes, you are right, it is an elementary calculation too.

Comment: @MaoWao Do you have a reference for the long list of equivalent definitions?

Comment: @MaoWao Could you also add a proof as to why $A\mapsto tr(A\rho)$ is WOT-continuous?

Comment: @MaoWao Are you still there?

Comment: Sorry, that was wrong. It is the $\sigma$-weak operator topology. (Normal states are WOT continuous on the unit ball, though).